# Using USB-6210, relay, to control a 12V double solenoid valve

Tags: relay, solenoid, daq

I am kinda new for the wiring of the relay. I have read some posts in forum regarding connecting the solenoid valve to the DAQ. But I am still not too sure how it all should be done. My objective is to use USB-6210, a crydom SSR (DC60 Series), to control a 12 V 5/2 way double solenoid valve for the extension and retraction of an actuator. I am just wondering how the schematic should be. Based on some googling, I come up with similar idea. Can someone give me some advice?

Since I have a double solenoid valve, I am wondering can I just wire one of the valve ( treating it as just a single valve?) or do I need to wire both valves (which I am not too sure how) to achieve my goal?

Thank you so much in advance!!!!
[image]

The valve I have:

https://trimantec.com/products/airtac-4v200-solenoid-valve-4v22008ft

The SSR I have:
http://www.crydom.com/en/products/catalog/dc60-series-dc-panel-mount.pdf

Comment: The answer depends entirely on the type of valve and whether it is stay put (which it sounds like) or spring return (which is what you're hoping for). Add a link to the datasheet **into your question** and link the datasheet for your SSR too. (Capital 'C' for Crydom.)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have added the link for the solenoid and the SSR. I am not to sure whether it would work based on what I have right now.... Does the DAQ play as input (by connecting the USB port to the computer...) Thanks for the help I am quite new in this area..

Comment: @steamrice Do not **VANADALIZE** your own question by removing the key information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We really need a link to a datasheet to be sure but with the low-resolution image on the linked page it appears that you have the wrong valve type.

[image]

*Figure 1. Upper is what you've got. Lower is what you'd like.*

Your SSR looks fine for controlling one coil but given that you've only got one output from your DAC you could consider changing to a relay.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvSMHH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. Relay switching arrangement.*

There are many relay modules available which will accept a logic-level input (5 V, a few mA) to switch a 5 V or 12 V relay coil. One of these would be quite adequate.

Comment: The DC coil is rated for 3W only. Seems like SSR is overkill.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. I am wondering what my valve would not work. Is it because my SSR is only able to control one coil? Could I potential get one more SSR ( 2 SSR to control my system?) or should I change to my valve to the spring return one?

Comment: Yes, you can only control one coil with one SSR. Either change the valve or add a second SSR or use the relay solution.

Comment: Thanks! I am wondering if I add a second SSR, does the wiring schematic would be the same (as what I have?) Also, does the DAQ play as input in this case (by connecting the USB port to the computer?)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the DAQ so I can't help you further with that.

Comment: No problem! I am just also wondering if the following would be possible. If I want to keep the whole system with one SSR, does adding a pull-up resistor solve my problem? I was reading pull-up resistor online but not too sure whether it would be able to control the two valves...